# Selenium webdriver retrieves an empty list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriverwait

I have this piece of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "../../bin/geckodriver", options = firefox_options)

driver.get('https://www.go2roues.com/shop/?category=7&puissance=null&brands=&batterieAmovible=false&connecte=false&livraison=false&capacite=false')

elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pf_pg__product")

print(elems)
```

When executing this code from a script I get an empty list as result:

> []

When executing the same code, using the same python binary, from my Python interpreter I get a non-empty list of objects:

> [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="37de724b-4b6d-634e-be5a-ac341a005380")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="d28dde48-858b-704d-ae32-f96c8e1f8448")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="adf7399e-437f-1e41-8c93-89a55e7f9b7d")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="6a5e1ba4-1ffd-2a48-8e32-26affb5ff27f")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="ebace849-3456-a145-8879-c7416ef0aaf3")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="db7ba515-91ad-1a42-9165-2839a815e54f")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="e1e4c457-90c5-bf4d-a7ef-e9bb718c8cf3")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="dbc64104-945f-6a48-b675-9c41fc6e018d")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="c30aaa20-d53e-694b-996f-96fbfdaf9b63")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="c702b3b5-edbe-2e4b-b348-c9af84e2e752")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="9d300c72-aeb8-7c44-abca-fd26b9bf80b5")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="031d6a78-4035-0647-ada8-26af216f323c")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="3b1b1667-8dcf-ac48-a846-6ad7aab42263")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="e7d61329-8477-7449-8ee9-cffa7879847d")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="5c6a312f-784a-7145-9563-7936e94ab55d")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="239f3ef9-64d1-a548-9b7f-2d773270a70c")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="c892f779-d99c-9e4e-97f4-bf72a15ee395")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="d5d9fe59-89d9-2a40-ba3f-74c085e31d22")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="08f103a6-6bd0-6841-b625-ae063b471beb")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="8aa46251-2a5d-5648-9044-c9940f79a245")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="da3cd602-88d9-ea41-b00d-f1a9f779a4fa")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="dd93f3c2-0369-2a42-9b50-78ba0c5b6bd6")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="8068f7da-509c-8a4f-9b8e-f260be982579")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="bf445291-d44d-7341-9a73-de5faa8da454")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="4885aaf0-f1db-354d-b6d5-3f376d254ea1")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="db66481c-210f-dc45-84ef-fefc938e5f4b")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="a7d4899a-3e6d-d744-8f42-496b1ef98b05")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="8a1c7a8b-2bd7-5e4f-b4a6-9c8b73341ef3")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="3e2b6d43-7571-eb44-898f-4ff57cf05ffc")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="10e6427c-5321-d74f-805c-2cb206e76e23")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="43492738-5926-474a-9d61-7832cc261786")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="78a8829b-4d58-1143-80e1-43fabd0fb857")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="4bc866f1-87ae-184c-a1f7-884d07da33df")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="f248744f-e7d3-734d-98aa-15e498a2189a")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="04e5a31d-1de2-0a4f-8875-090e4529fea4")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="a18d837a-6a6d-b645-81bc-236142b30a2e")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="9329bbc1-c5e7-e647-bdd9-2097ddf065bd")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="f24de1ee-7168-ca42-883f-59d7c110bc37")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="76f50a49-cb5b-1c4d-94a7-4610e43bd981")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="d8a37df2-cf8a-da45-bd24-6f2f5d1a50e7")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="1fcadcaa-1e69-2b45-ad73-0697b38f6b31")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="cf45ff9c-4e3d-4b40-a5c4-88237efaf368")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="2ed04309-1a75-ad42-88e8-c11456b5f232")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="68a60a61-2b5d-e048-8ad7-f7e5b852888d")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="ad3fdb6c-55d7-e94c-b702-5cf6fff30c12")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="8b8f89c6-5512-7140-b05c-76fb97cec394")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="4e9c61f3-e662-f945-9853-43caf57e3270")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="f5d01c4d-ba3e-7a45-8a58-8ad5af62ff41")>,
> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement
> (session="db14e25f-5479-504c-956c-8672a965327d",
> element="0196f1d6-80d4-5844-a688-e80354597bc4")>]

I have no idea where the problem comes from. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a delay before getting the elements list.
The desired web elements should be fully loaded before accessing them.
The simplest way to make your code work will be by simply adding some delay:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "../../bin/geckodriver", options = firefox_options)

driver.get('https://www.go2roues.com/shop/?category=7&puissance=null&brands=&batterieAmovible=false&connecte=false&livraison=false&capacite=false')

time.sleep(10)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pf_pg__product")

print(elems)
```

To make it better you should use explicit waits like the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "../../bin/geckodriver", options = firefox_options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://www.go2roues.com/shop/?category=7&puissance=null&brands=&batterieAmovible=false&connecte=false&livraison=false&capacite=false')

#wait for the foirst element matching the passed locator presence
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".pf_pg__product")))

#add a short delay to make all the elements loaded
time.sleep(0.6)

#get the elements list
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pf_pg__product")

print(elems)
```

Comment: Ah ok! I see now. Im stupid! Which goes to show, reading the docs is important. Thank you

Comment: No, not just reading. When you read it you don't really care and understand, but when you face that problem practically - this is what gives you to understand that. It is also called "experience"  :)